# SystemError: <class 'cv2.VideoCapture'> returned a result with an error set

Tags: opencv, python-3.6

I am getting this error since Morning. Till yesterday, the script was working perfectly fine. 
I have unistalled opencv and then reinstalled it . That also dosent fix the problem.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('WindowName',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xFF==ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the script is working fine in my friend's system.

Comment: Are you using anaconda python ? Which OS ?

Comment: Yes I am using anaconda, Windows 10

Comment: Did you installed `opencv-contrib` as well ?

Comment: No I didn't installed that

Comment: Please install that and let me know

Comment: it's showig the same error again

Comment: Sounds like your system has forgotten that the webcam exists. Is it plugged in?

Comment: yes its the laptop webcam   But my webcam is working ,only in the script its not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you using it on a Mac? Try this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_AVFOUNDATION)
```

Hope it will solve the issue.